# How can I use Visual Studio Code to debug Django with an IP address defined by myself? (By that I would test my app on an android phone)

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I'm aware that when I set up my server with `python manage.py runserver [my custom IP address]` I can choose what IP and port will be chosen. But when I use VScode in debug mode I don't know where I can define the server other than `127.0.0.0.1:8000`. Having `127.0.0.0.1:8000` I can access the page just by my pc (win 10).

I need to change the address, because I'm unable to open my page on my android phone (for testing with this debugger), but I don't know where and how.

I suspect that it can be somehow defined in `launch.json`, but I haven't found any information about that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by giving the IP as args to launch.json.

```
#launch.json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current file",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",

            "args": ["runserver", "192.168.1.0:8000"], //or whatever IP you want to use

            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've tried without quotation marks, like in shell - totally forgot about differences in defining IP in JSON files! I should go sleep sooner yesterday :). Thank you for your answer!